# How to remove associated products from configurable product?

Tags: product, configurable-product, associated-products

I want to remove all associated product from configurable product .

How can i do this

I m trying to do like this

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(11);
$product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds();
$product->save();
```

but its not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the below code:

> ```
> Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
>     ->saveProducts($product, array());
> ```

Send saveProducts() ***second params as empty arrya***

Your code like this:

> ```
> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(11);
> Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
>     ->saveProducts($product, array());
> ```

Comment: How can this be achieved in Magento 2?

Comment: @Nausif did you find this solution in Magento 2? If yes, can you guide...

Answer (score 0):

For those (like myself) who are here for a Magento2 answer:

If we're doing it programmatically using `objectManager` (I know, I know)

```
//Set up connection to Magento instance
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../app/bootstrap.php'; //My file is in the pub dir
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

//Load the product
$productId = '12345';
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); 

//Here's the clear bit (be careful with this)
$product->setAssociatedProductIds([]);
$product->save();
```