# Programmatically Remove Associated Products From Grouped Product

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products, associated-products

I have a grouped product and am looking to remove all associated products from it programmatically. I tried using a similar method as one would use for a configurable product found here:

[How to remove associated products from configurable product?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85379/how-to-remove-associated-products-from-configurable-product)

But there is no comparable saveProducts() method for grouped products because there is no resource 'catalog/product_type_grouped'. I've tried to follow the saveAction method used in Adminhtml/controllers/catalog/product/ProductController, but haven't found the piece of code that saves the associated products selected in the admin form.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This is a variation of some code in the _initProductSave() method of the same controller:

```
$groupedProduct->setGroupedLinkData(array());
$groupedProduct->save();
```